# Model Possible States of values of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to model possible states in which a checkbox can exist in Javascript?
I currently have 3 checkboxes. TakeDown, Ban and Not applicable. 
If either of takedown or ban is selected, Notapplicable checkbox has to be disabled.
If Notapplicable has been selected, takedown and ban checkboxes should be disabled.

I have got this working currently in the following format:

https://jsfiddle.net/ozum4q0s/16/

However I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this. If this extends to more options, the number of conditions can be a bit crazy.

HTML:

```
<div id ="possibleDecisions">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="TakeDown">
                                <span>Take Down</span>
                            </input>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Ban">
                                <span>Ban</span>
                            </input>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Notapplicable">
                                <span>Not applicable</span>
                            </input>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#possibleDecisions").delegate("table", "click", function (elem) {
        var takeDownCheckValue = $(this).find('#TakeDown').is(':checked');
        var banCheckValue = $(this).find('#Ban').is(':checked');
        var notApplicableCheckValue = $(this).find('#Notapplicable').is(':checked');

        if (takeDownCheckValue === true || banCheckValue === true) {
            $(this).find('#Notapplicable').prop("disabled", true);
        }

        if (takeDownCheckValue === false && banCheckValue === false) {
            $(this).find('#Notapplicable').prop("disabled", false);
        }

        if (notApplicableCheckValue === true) {
            $(this).find('#TakeDown').prop("disabled", true);
            $(this).find('#Ban').prop("disabled", true);
        }

        if (notApplicableCheckValue === false) {
            $(this).find('#TakeDown').prop("disabled", false);
            $(this).find('#Ban').prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why do you need delegate? are creating new dom?

Comment: Yeah you're right. I'm not creating any new dom. Probably a find might do as well .

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#Ban,#TakeDown,#Notapplicable").click(function() {
      if($(this).attr("id")=="Notapplicable") 
        $("#Ban,#TakeDown").prop("disabled", $(this).prop("checked"));
      else
        $("#Notapplicable").prop("disabled", $("#Ban").prop("checked")||$("#TakeDown").prop("checked"));
      });
});
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/hogafenigi/edit?js

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("input").click(function(event) {
      var current_id = event.target.id;
      if(current_id == "Notapplicable"){
        if($("#"+current_id).is(":checked") == true){
          $("input").prop("disabled",true);
          $("#Notapplicable").prop("disabled",false);
        }else{
          $("input").prop("disabled",false);
        }
      }
      else{
        if($("#"+current_id).is(":checked") == true){
          $("input").prop("disabled",false);
          $("#Notapplicable").prop("disabled",true);
        }else{
          $("input").prop("disabled",false);
        }
      }
      console.log(current_id);
      
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="possibleDecisions">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Actions</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="TakeDown">
<span>Take Down</span>
</label>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Ban">
<span>Ban</span>
</label>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Notapplicable">
<span>Not applicable</span>
</label>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```